Google App Engine Flexible environment for Python with Flask and Gunicorn
I used to have a setup for my google app engine python project with the following app.yaml:
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3

resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 2.3
  disk_size_gb: 10
  volumes:
  - name: ramdisk1
    volume_type: tmpfs
    size_gb: 0.5

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1

And a requirements.txt that looks like this:
Flask==0.12.2
gunicorn==19.7.1
numpy==1.8.0
scipy==1.5.3
mysql-connector-python==8.0.23


But Google made it so you can no longer deploy using python version 3, now instead the app.yaml file must look like this or something similar:
runtime_config:
  operating_system: "ubuntu22"
  runtime_version: "3.12"


This makes my requirements.txt not work and I keep changing it, my latest version is this:
Flask==2.0.3
gunicorn==22.0.0
numpy==2.1.1
scipy==1.14.0
mysql-connector-python==9.0.0
Jinja2==3.1.1
MarkupSafe==2.1.1
Werkzeug==2.0.3

No matter how much I change it or what versions I change for these libraries, I always get some sort of error whether it be gunicorn, flask, Werkzeug, or Jinja2.
This latest version gives me an error when trying to deploying with gcloud app deploy: ImportError: cannot import name 'Markup' from 'jinja2' (/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jinja2/init.py). I also use Python 3.10 instead of 3.12 since it seems to give me more errors.
If anyone can give me a requirements.txt that works with gunicorn and Flask with a python version that can still be deployed that would be most appreciated.

My Coworker ended up figuring out, we use python version 3.11 with the following requirements.txt file:
Flask==2.1.3
Werkzeug==2.3.7
gunicorn==22.0.0
numpy==2.1.1
scipy==1.14.0
mysql-connector-python==9.0.0


